# Why is the latency on one LVM volume consistently higher?

Tags: lvm, latency

I've got a server with LVM over RAID1. One of the volumes has a consistently higher IO latency (as measured by the diskstats_latency munin plugin) than the other volumes from the same group.

[image: Relevant munin graph]

As you can see, the dark orange /root volume has consistently high IO latency. Actually ten times the average latency of the physical devices. It also has the highest Min and Max values. My main concern are not the peaks, which occur under high load, but the constant load on (semi-)idle.

The server is running Debian Squeeze with the VServer kernel and has four VServer containers and one KVM guest.

I'm looking for ways to fix - or at least understand - this situation.

Here're some parts of the system configuration:

```
root@kvmhost2:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system--host-root
                       19G  3.8G   14G  22% /
tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   16G  224K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0              942M   37M  858M   5% /boot
/dev/mapper/system--host-isos
                       28G   19G  8.1G  70% /srv/isos
/dev/mapper/system--host-vs_a
                       30G   23G  6.0G  79% /var/lib/vservers/a
/dev/mapper/system--host-vs_b
                      5.0G  594M  4.1G  13% /var/lib/vservers/b
/dev/mapper/system--host-vs_c
                      5.0G  555M  4.2G  12% /var/lib/vservers/c
/dev/loop0            4.4G  4.4G     0 100% /media/debian-6.0.0-amd64-DVD-1
/dev/loop1            4.4G  4.4G     0 100% /media/debian-6.0.0-i386-DVD-1
/dev/mapper/system--host-vs_d
                       74G   55G   16G  78% /var/lib/vservers/d
root@kvmhost2:~# cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=16500836k,nr_inodes=4125209,mode=755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
/dev/mapper/system--host-root / ext3 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/md0 /boot ext3 rw,sync,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/system--host-isos /srv/isos ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/system--host-vs_a /var/lib/vservers/a ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/system--host-vs_b /var/lib/vservers/b ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/system--host-vs_c /var/lib/vservers/c ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/loop0 /media/debian-6.0.0-amd64-DVD-1 iso9660 ro,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop1 /media/debian-6.0.0-i386-DVD-1 iso9660 ro,relatime 0 0
/dev/mapper/system--host-vs_d /var/lib/vservers/d ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered 0 0
root@kvmhost2:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      975779968 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      979840 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
root@kvmhost2:~# iostat -x
Linux 2.6.32-5-vserver-amd64 (kvmhost2)         06/28/2012      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           3.09    0.14    2.92    1.51    0.00   92.35

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda              23.25   161.12    7.46   37.90   855.27  1596.62    54.05     0.13    2.80   1.76   8.00
sdb              22.82   161.36    7.36   37.66   850.29  1596.62    54.35     0.54   12.01   1.80   8.09
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.14     0.02    38.44     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00   53.55  198.16   768.01  1585.25     9.35     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.48   20.21    16.70   161.71     8.62     0.26   12.72   0.77   1.60
dm-1              0.00     0.00    3.62   10.03    28.94    80.21     8.00     0.19   13.68   1.59   2.17
dm-2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     9.17     0.00    9.64   6.42   0.00
dm-3              0.00     0.00    6.73    0.41    53.87     3.28     8.00     0.02    3.44   0.12   0.09
dm-4              0.00     0.00   17.45   18.18   139.57   145.47     8.00     0.42   11.81   0.76   2.69
dm-5              0.00     0.00    2.50   46.38   120.50   371.07    10.06     0.69   14.20   0.46   2.26
dm-6              0.00     0.00    0.02    0.10     0.67     0.81    12.53     0.01   75.53  18.58   0.22
dm-7              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     7.99     0.00   11.24   9.45   0.00
dm-8              0.00     0.00   22.69  102.76   407.25   822.09     9.80     0.97    7.71   0.39   4.95
dm-9              0.00     0.00    0.06    0.08     0.50     0.62     8.00     0.07  481.23  11.72   0.16

root@kvmhost2:~# ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 59 May 11 11:19 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Jun  5 15:08 system--host-kvm1 -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Jun  5 15:08 system--host-kvm2 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Jun  5 15:06 system--host-isos -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 May 11 11:19 system--host-root -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Jun  5 15:06 system--host-swap -> ../dm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Jun  5 15:06 system--host-vs_d -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Jun  5 15:06 system--host-vs_b -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Jun  5 15:06 system--host-vs_c -> ../dm-7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Jun  5 15:06 system--host-vs_a -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Jun  5 15:08 system--host-kvm3 -> ../dm-1
root@kvmhost2:~#
```

Comment: Are you masking out partition on that Munin chart? I am confused as to why it would show `/` multiple times. I am also concerned as to why it shows a /root partition when your mount listing doesn't show you have a /root partition. Maybe Munin is measuring latency differently for a folder versus a mount?

Comment: @Andy: yes all `system-...` partitions are LVs with masked names.

Comment: It may be helpful to add the output from cat /proc/partitions and cat /proc/diskstats to your question.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I've now noticed the same behavior on a completely different hardware. Also Debian squeeze, with the same layout, though.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to check your partition, device mapper, file-system, raid stripe alignment

```
iostat x
```

Compare `blk_read` and `blk_wrtn` against all the layers, they should be even if everything is aligned. Also please post the output of `df -h` and `cat /proc/mounts`

You'll probably find that you are doing far more reads/writes on that particular logical volume moreso than any others.

Alignment is key to having healthy, fast I/O - otherwise, you are needlessly multiplying r/w between all the storage layers.

Bear in mind, if a given partition is more active than any other it will also cause what you describe. Along with the choice of file system and flags set for when that FS is mounted. Simply adding  `noatime` and `nodiratime` could be all it takes to reduce the I/O activity a little, and thus, the latency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At least now I can exclude this as a problem :-) The IO counts from iostat do add up properly across the levels and the root LV has less IOPs than other LVs.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the mlog is stored on only one of the disks. Just type 
`lvs -a -o +devices` to get an overview what data is stored on which device.

You could prevent this by putting the mlog on another device.